# Is a naturalistic language without countable nouns possible?

Tags: conlang-creation, morphology, naturalism, nouns

Is a naturalistic language without count nouns possible, thus having only mass nouns? This would mean having many words for things with water: a sea, an ocean, a bottle of water, a puddle, etc.
What about compounding to get these words?

Comment: The obvious answer is yes. You could even have a language with no nouns. Of course you might not be able to describe anything, which might make the language not very useful. I suspect this is not what you want, in that case you need to elaborate a few more requirements for the language, to exclude the trivial solutions. Also, by countable do you mean finite or countably infinite?

Comment: Or do you mean a language without count nouns (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_noun) but with mass nouns (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun)?

Comment: Yes. I'll clarify it @Jetpack

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a matter of fact, Mandarin Chinese can be considered to be such a language - it treats every noun as a mass noun. Every noun requires a "measure word" for counting, like "bottle" in "four bottles of water" or "sheet" in "ten sheets of paper". Chinese has a considerable list of these (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chinese_classifiers) but there's no particular reason that a language with only mass nouns would need to have so many classifiers.

Comment: Actually Chinese does have specifically noncount nouns just like English, and they do interact differently with classifiers. Indeed, they cannot be used directly with a number+classifier at all: you can't count "five muds" in Chinese any more than you can in English. That's discussed in the Wikipedia article on classifiers [and also here](http://phonetics.linguistics.ucla.edu/wpl/issues/wpl17/papers/26_liu.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. A language can treat all nouns as mass nouns and require [classifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifier_(linguistics)) when counting objects.